Regression with a 0-1 variable. Should be the same as running a t-test, but I get a different p-value
I have a dataset in R where I have volatility estimates (in my case, just standard deviation of minute returns on that day) for different days:
Date, Volatility, DayType

The variable DayType is 0 or 1 (no other options - no NA either), and it denotes whether a date meets some specific criteria or not - let's say that a day can either be normal or special. I want to run a simple test to see whether volatility on special day is different from a volatility on a normal day.
Since DayType can only have two values, the simple regression analysis should be equivalent to a t-test. But I get two different p-values, and I am wondering what I've misunderstood.
First, I can run a simple regression:
MyModel1=lm(Volatility ~ DayType, data=MyData)
summary(MyModel1)

This will give me a p-value for DayType.
Alternatively, I can split the dataset into two datasets and run a t-test.
library(dplyr)
MyDataSpecial=MyData %>% filter(DayType==1)
MyDataNormal=MyData %>% filter(DayType==0)

t.test(MyDataSpecial$Volatility, MyDataNormal$Volatility, alternative="two.sided")

This will give a different p-value. Can you help me understand what is wrong here?
Here is also another example with mtcars dataset:
library(dplyr)
MyData=mtcars

#Regression
MyModel1=lm(mpg ~ vs, data=MyData)
summary(MyModel1)

#t-test
MyData1=MyData %>% filter(vs==1)
MyData2=MyData %>% filter(vs==0)

t.test(MyData1$mpg, MyData2$mpg, alternative="two.sided")

Thank you!

please always share the data. use dput

The interesting thing is that, while the previous answers are undoubtedly technically correct (set var.equal=TRUE), they do not explain the reasons behind this.
There are 2 "versions" of the 2-sample t-test; the "original recipe", aka Student's t-test, which relies on a assumption of equal variances. And the Welch t-test, which does not need this assumption. The Student's t-test can either significantly exceed its nominal $\alpha$ error rate, when the variances are different, or be much more conservative than its nominal $\alpha$ level, depending on which sample has the largest variance (the one with the smallest or largest sample size). The Welch t-test remedies this. In fact, many authors/textbooks advise to always use the Welch t-test, even when the variances are similar and the samples balanced; for example here or here. This is because the Welch t-test works almost identically to the Student's t test when the conditions are met (equal variances, balanced samples), and much better when they are not. Because of this, many software default to using the Welch t-test. This is why t.test() defaults to "unequal variances", i.e. Welch. But lm() assumes equal variances.
Now, in your case, because you got different p-values (one assumes different enough that you had to ask a question), you have different variances, and possibly unequal sample sizes, you should use var.equal=FALSE (or leave it at default). That will give you the proper p-value. Now, if they are both significant (or both not significant) the difference does not matter much; but if they are quite different, believe t.test(), not lm().

And OP should account for variance heterogeneity in the regression model. The gls function from the nlme package enables this.

If you set var.equal=TRUE in the t.test() call, they should be equivalent. Eg:
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(0:1, 100, rep=TRUE)
y <- rnorm(length(y)) + x
dtf <- data.frame(x, y)

summary(lm(y ~ x, data=dtf))
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x, data = dtf)
# 
# Residuals:
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -5.53966 -1.73653 -0.25531  1.60254  7.42146 
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept) -0.21661    0.39233 -0.5521  0.58214  
# x            1.34139    0.56629  2.3687  0.01981 *
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 2.8292 on 98 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.054154,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.044503 
# F-statistic:  5.611 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.01981
# 

t.test(y ~ x, data=dtf, var.equal=TRUE)
# 
#   Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  y by x
# t = -2.36875, df = 98, p-value = 0.01981
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between 
# group 0 and group 1 is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -2.4651653 -0.2176130
# sample estimates:
# mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
#     -0.21660528      1.12478389 
# 


Do you mean that this is a copy of your answer (I don't think so, time stamps are pretty close together and the answers aren't more similar than expected) or that there should be a duplicate question on this topic?  There are lots of related Qs but I don't see an exact dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354698/how-to-make-a-t-test-without-a-dataset/67355946#67355946, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68269729/reversed-signs-of-test-statistic-using-lm-vs-t-test, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59115035/lm-and-t-testvar-equal-true-differ-on-one-machine-but-not-on-another-poss ...

The methods in lm() and t.test() are different.
Try the t.test with var.equal = TRUE:
t.test(MyData1$mpg, MyData2$mpg, alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = TRUE)

        Two Sample t-test

data:  MyData1$mpg and MyData2$mpg
t = 4.8644, df = 30, p-value = 3.416e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  4.606732 11.274221
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 24.55714  16.61667

# extract p.value from the t.test

p_value_t_test <-
t.test(MyData1$mpg,
    MyData2$mpg,
    alternative = "two.sided",
    var.equal = TRUE
) |>
    {\(x) x$p.value}()


# Linear Regression
MyModel1 = lm(mpg ~ vs, data = MyData)
model_summary = summary(MyModel1)

# Extract p-value for the DayType (vs) coefficient
p_value_lm <- model_summary$coefficients["vs", "Pr(>|t|)"]

p.values are now the same
> p_value_t_test
[1] 3.415937e-05
> p_value_lm
[1] 3.415937e-05

